# Button does not work?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So what im trying to do here is to show and hide div when i click button but it does not work and i dont know why.

```
script

$(document).ready(function(){

    $('article').addClass("hidden");

    $('#hide').click(function() {
    var $this = $(this);

        if ($this.hasClass("hidden")) {
            $(this).removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible");

        } else {
            $(this).removeClass("visible").addClass("hidden");
        }
    });
});
```

Here is CSS

```
.hidden>div {
    display: none;
}

.visible>div {
    display: block;
}
```

Here is HTML

```
<article>
    <button type="button" id="hide"></button>
    <div>
        <img />
        <img />
    </div>
</article>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of putting if condition and then removing and adding classes, you can just toggle the class hidden.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('article').addClass("hidden");

  $('#hide').click(function() {
    $('article').toggleClass('hidden')
  });
});
```

See this working demo: [Toggle class](https://jsfiddle.net/yyd4knzp/)

Answer (score 2):

You should add class `hidden` to `article` instead of `button`

```
var $this = $(this).parent();
```

Selector `.hidden>div` adds style to first `div` child of element with class `hidden`.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $('article').addClass("hidden");

  $( '#hide' ).click(function() {

    if ( $( 'article' ).hasClass( "hidden" ) ) {

        $( 'article' ).removeClass("hidden").addClass("visible");

    } else {

        $('article').removeClass("visible").addClass("hidden");
    }

  });
});
```

You can use toggle also

Answer (score 0):

Jquery has a [toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) function that hides and shows selected elements. It also has [hide](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) and [show](http://api.jquery.com/show/) functions that mean your css isn't needed.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  // Hide the div to start with.
  $('#divToHide').hide();

  // When the button is clicked, toggle the div's visibility.
  $('#hide').click(function() {
    $('#divToHide').toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
  <article>
    <button type="button" id="hide">Click me to toggle the visibility of the div</button>
    <div id="divToHide">
      Hello World!
    </div>
  </article>
</body>
```